# Show custom application image in task manager on ICS or JB

Tags: android, screenshot, preview, taskmanager

As far as I see on Android 4.0 (or higher) default task manager shows last screenshot from program with program icon no the top left. See image:

[image: screenshot]

My question is how to change application's image (not icon) in task manager to custom? Don't ask me why, I just need it.

After some research I found similar question on SO: [Show black preview screen in task manager on ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984083/show-black-preview-screen-in-task-manager-on-ics). But it doesn't answers my question.

Also I didn't find any API to work with this task manager.

So I decided to show custom image when program (activity) turns off. From [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) I found that I need to override method `onPause`. So I decided to code a small program. It's very easy to understand:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(createImageView("/sdcard/program-image.jpg"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        setContentView(createImageView("/sdcard/task-manager-image.jpg"));
        super.onPause();
    }

    private ImageView createImageView(String pathFile)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplication());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathFile));
        imageView.invalidate();
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

The `task-manager-image` really shows for a while after pressing Home button, but task manager shows only `program-image`.

So is there any good solution to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I doubt that there is a definitive time when it takes the screenshot. You can block the screenshots using `FLAG_SECURE` (see http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html), and you can read the image from `ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo`, but I do not believe that you can change the image via any public API.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your reply. So how can I show some image for a second (or other time)? It seems to be the only solution now. Thanks.

Comment: Again, the issue is that you have no control over the timing of when the screenshot is taken, so you have no idea when you need to be displaying that image.