# When does Android take its recent apps switcher screenshot?

Tags: android, screenshot, preview, taskmanager

I am developing an app that has private information and should not display a real screenshot in Android's recent app switcher. I've tried a variation of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639335/show-custom-application-image-in-task-manager-on-ics-or-jb), by setting the content view to an ImageView inside the onPause function, but it seems that the operating system takes a screenshot before the content view is changed to the custom image.

I am also aware of [setting the window's layout parameter flags to secure](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html), making the screenshot completely white, but I'd hope that there would be a way to customize the screenshot.

So, I'm wondering at what point that Android takes a screenshot of the app for the app switcher (specifically in KitKat and Lollipop).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT**

It is no longer possible to customize the screenshot which system uses to present the thumbnail in the recent apps.

**Old answer**

Take a look at method `Activity.onCreateThumbnail` - this is exactly what you're looking for as it let you draw your own thumbnail for Recent screen.

You get `Canvas` as one of the parameters in which you can draw (or not draw at all) directly. The main point is that you have to return `true` from this method, which indicates that system won't draw thumbnail itself.

The simpliest solution would be:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateThumbnail (Bitmap outBitmap, Canvas canvas) {
    // Do nothing or draw on Canvas
    return true;
}
```

or if you want to draw your own `Bitmap`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateThumbnail (Bitmap outBitmap, Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could I please get a code example on how to use both the bitmap and the canvas? I also tried that earlier and did not know how to manipulate the two.

Comment: @LouieBertoncin added example

Comment: Ok, here's what I did to use the two parameters: `outBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myBitmap);` `canvas.drawBitmap(outBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());`

Comment: @LouieBertoncin you must not modify incoming `outBitmap` - it is already created by the system. Java is still pass-by-value, so by replacing `outBitmap` reference you're not changing anything. Instead, you must draw your `Bitmap` directly on `Canvas`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361231/android-draw-bitmap-within-canvas

Comment: The method never seems to be called for me. I have a log statement inside the body that never prints. Is there any sort of setup for this method?

Comment: @LouieBertoncin are you still using `FLAG_SECURE`? As far as I know, it will prevent system from calling `onCreateThumbnail`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81414/discussion-between-louie-bertoncin-and-dmitry-zaitsev).

Comment: For some reason, the onCreateThumbnail() method never got called, but this should be the correct answer and it is thoroughly explained. Thank you @DmitryZaitsev

Comment: This approach is not working also because onCreateThumbnail method is not called.

Comment: so how can we achieve custom image for recent history list ? Any workaround ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible, because I could see it working on [CommerzBank application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.commerzbanking.mobil).

Comment: From Activity documentation for onCreateThumbnail(): "This method was deprecated in API level 28. Method doesn't do anything and will be removed in the future."

Comment: @azizbekian I checked now - CommerzBank app just set FLAG SECURE. App disable screenshots for the whole application