# Android : Unable to screenshot after using method FLAG_SECURE

Tags: android, screenshot

Due to security reason, I would like to hide the content of the apps when it goes background.

Understand that using below method could done this job, but I would like to have the screenshot function still working.

*getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);*

Is there any workaround or other kind of method that could hide/blur the content of the apps when it goes background without compromise the screenshot function?

Comment: Instead of using FLAG_SECURE try setting the thumbnail manually (to a black screen or something secure like that). http://stackoverflow.com/a/31012018/833647

Comment: onCreateThumbnail seems to be not supported anymore on Android framework. Do you still have alternatives on this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas! Good luck! :)

Comment: I still need a solution for this, did you had any solutions yet?

Comment: Any other solution for that issue on these days? :(

Comment: We can use the below code on base activity to do that
-->
public override fun onPause() {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
    super.onPause()
}

public override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
}